# K2 Workflow Deadlock Issue while calling stored procedure

Tags: nintex-workflow, k2, k2-blackpearl

I am using k2five with k2.net. I need to send email if there is any deadlock in k2. we are already sending email from procedure but deadlock only happens in k2. in stored procedure there is no deadlock.

How to send mail on k2five error deadlock?